# Combine polymorphic include conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

Using Rails 3. I have the following code:

```
@reviews = @user.reviews.includes(:user, :reviewable => :photos).where(:reviewable_type => "Shop")
@reviews = @user.reviews.includes(:user, :reviewable => :country_days => [:shops => :photos]).where(:reviewable_type => "Country")
```

I can't run this query in a single `@reviews` because `Country` has `country_days`, but `Shop` doesn't have `country_days`. If I do this:

```
@reviews = @user.reviews.includes(:user, :reviewable => [:photos, :country_days => [:shops => :photos]])
```

This code won't work because for `reviewable_type == "Shop"`, it doesn't have `country_days`.

How can I combine the first 2 queries together?

Comment: I think unless you want to use `find_by_sql` the easiest way is to combine the two arrays that you get as results in ruby itself.

Comment: `@reviews = @user.reviews.includes(:user, :reviewable => :photos).includes(:user, :reviewable => :country_days => [:shops => :photos]).where(:reviewable_type => "Shop")` have no idea whether it will work

Comment: @ted, what about `:reviewable_type => "Country"`?